# Why does dereferencing a char** value (pointer-to-pointer-to-char) differ from dereferencing a char*[] (pointer-to-char array)?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, char, dereference

If a char* array is defined with at least one value, the first value can be indexed via "arr[0]" and printed successfully with the format specifier "%s". However, if a char** is defined, it will segfault if the first element is attempted to be printed with printf or similar functions (with string format specifier).

Below is a block of code that demonstrates how this works:

```
char* s = "test";
char** sa = { s };
char* arr[] = { s };

// Prints pointers of each variable
puts("\nTest 1:");
puts("----------------------------------------");
printf("s:\t%p\n", s);
printf("sa:\t%p\n\n", sa);

// Dereferences pointers, prints as pointers (even though *s is a char)
puts("Test 2:");
puts("----------------------------------------");
printf("s:\t%p\n", *s);
printf("sa:\t%p\n\n", *sa);

// Prints strings of each variable
puts("Test 3:");
puts("----------------------------------------");
printf("s:\t%s\n", s);
printf("sa:\t%s\n\n", sa);

// Prints first element of array (works unlike *(char**), which I would think are the same)
puts("Test 4:");
puts("----------------------------------------");
printf("arr:\t%s\n", arr[0]);
printf("arr:\t%s\n\n", *arr);

// Prints strings of dereferenced pointers (segfault for sa)
puts("Test 5:");
puts("----------------------------------------");
printf("s:\t%s\n", *s);
printf("sa:\t%s\n\n", *sa);
```

This is the potential output:

```
Test 1:
----------------------------------------
s:      0x10013bf2c
sa:     0x10013bf2c

Test 2:
----------------------------------------
s:      0x74
sa:     0x65540a0074736574

Test 3:
----------------------------------------
s:      test
sa:     test

Test 4:
----------------------------------------
arr:    test
arr:    test

Test 5:
----------------------------------------
zsh: segmentation fault  ./test2
```

I understand that dereferencing variable *s* returns the ASCII value for the first character, which is "t" in this case. However, I'm confused on why variable *sa* doesn't dereference to the first string in the array? Shouldn't dereferencing the double pointer return the pointer to *s*?

I've tried returning strings from the pointer *sa* returns, but it only segfaults, meaning that the pointer for *sa* under **Test 2** has no meaning or association with the string bounded to *s*.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I worded it wrong; I'm just confused how in the example above, sa[0] will not print a string (same thing as *sa) when printf("%s", *sa) is used. Though it's not shown in my code, it will segfault.

Comment: @RyanPereira You have warnings on?

Comment: Please add the code that prints using `%s`. It would help us understand what you are asking exactly. Consider this, for example: you mention a pointer to an array, but there are none in your code. There's a pointer to pointer, but it isn't the same thing. Are you asking why `s` and `sa`, despite having the same value as shown by printing them with `%p` in Test 1, give different results when printed with `%s`? Did you want to use `%s` in Test 2?

Comment: My apologies, I'm getting lost in the source of this issue. I've edited the question.

Comment: Consider that `char* arr[]` declares an array of pointers to char, not a pointer to an array of chars! If you want a pointer to an array of chars you need to use `char (*arr)[]`. Honestly this is a very confusing topic and I'd suggest to leave it aside for now. If you want to explore it, try https://cdecl.org/, and the rule to understand these declarations is called the "right-left rule", or the "spiral rule".

Comment: Understood, I'm using C for an assignment however and I am indeed looking to construct an array of pointer-to-char values. Thank you for the resource, I will look into it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters you do not have an array. In this declaration

```
char** sa = { s };
```

you declared a pointer of the type `char **` that is initialized by the value of the variable `s` of the type `char *`.

```
char* s = "test";
char** sa = { s };
```

The compiler should issue a message that there is no implicit conversion between these two pointer types.

The difference between these two outputs

```
printf("s:\t%p\n", *s);
printf("sa:\t%p\n\n", *sa);
```

is that in the first case the expression `*s` has the type `char` that is promoted to the type `int`. That is only the first byte of the string literal is read as a value.

In the second case the expression `*sa` is considered as an expression of the pointer type `char *`. So the function reads the memory occupied by the expression as a memory storing a pointer of the size `4` or `8` bytes depending on the used system without any promotions as in the first case.

As for your comment to my answer

> Also, when the char* version of sa (when sa is dereferenced) is
> attempted to be printed as a string using the format specifier "%s", a
> segfault occurs. This is the main source of what I'm a bit
> confused
> about

When the pointer `sa` is dereferenced  then its value is the value composed by characters stored in the string literal and this value is interpreted as a pointer when the conversion specifier `%s` is used. That of course results in undefined behavior.

See the output of the code you showed in your question

```
sa:     0x65540a0074736574
```

This part of the outputted value `74736574` represents the word "test" written in the reverse order `"tset"`.

You could write instead

```
char* s = "test";
char** sa = { &s };
```

and then

```
printf( "%s\n", *sa );
```

In this case the pointer `sa` will contain the address of the declared pointer `s` and the expression `*sa` yields the value stored in the pointer `s` that is the address of the first character of the string literal `"test"`.

Comment: This makes sense. Perhaps I should've added more code/output to the body of my question; afaik a pointer-to-pointer-to-char is similar to a 2D char array. Also, when the char* version of sa (when sa is dereferenced) is attempted to be printed as a string using the format specifier "%s", a segfault occurs. This is the main source of what I'm a bit confused about

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot more sense!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `char **` and `char *` types are not compatible - as you can see with plain eye one has more indirections that need to be applied in order to retrieve the original `char` object.

In C you can use the initialiser syntax (`{` and `}`) to assign even to non array types so `char** sa = { s };` is equivalent to just a simple assignment with `=`.

Then furthermore you are then accessing the `s` pointer by doing `sa` which is then indirected with `*sa` and here we have potential UB because `*sa` is yielding an object that is not guaranteed to have valid location.

*The UB actually happens when printf tries to access said location*

It's because (for example in 32 bit architecture) `*sa` is reading 4 bytes of the `s` string and interpreting them as address (depending on endianness).

The difference between:

```
char** sa = { s };
char* arr[] = { s };
```

Is the fact that in the first case `{` and `}` are superfluous and doesn't mean nothing while in the second case they refer to the fact that we are initialising nested elements of the array (i.e. `char *` with `s` which is also `char *`). This would create (for the second case) an array with a single element.

There is difference between array and pointer.

Comment: Ah, so the brackets are basically skipped in the first line?

Comment: @RyanPereira Well that is true yes. The `{` and `}` braces are nothing more but a way to specify which object gets assigned to which sub-object when initialising aggregates (structures or arrays) - otherwise they are kinda confusing (and yes do nothing).